# nil and nilpotent ideal

Tags: ring-theory, nilpotence

$T_{n} (F)$ is  Algebra of upper triangular $n \times n $ matrices over field $ F$.

> Can we find an ideal of the algebra $\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$ that is nil but not nilpotent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: consider, for each $n$, the ideal $I_n$ in $T_n(F)$ of matrices with $0$ on the diagonal. Each element in this ideal has index of nilpotency at most $n$, and this index  is attained by matrices with non-zero overdiagonal elements.Thus $I_n$ is a nilpotent ideal, with index of nilpotency exactly $n$.

Now,  the ideal: 
$$I=\bigoplus_{n} I_n\subset \prod_{n\ge 2}T_n(F) $$
is such a non-nilpotent nilideal.

Indeed, any element in this direct sum, being a finite sum of nilpotent elements, is nilpotent. However, it has elements with index of nilpotency as large as we please, so there exists no natural number $N$ such that
$$I^N=\bigoplus_{n\ge 2} I_n^N=\bigoplus_{n\ge 2} \{0\}.$$

Comment: Can you give more explanation about the   "$I=\bigoplus_{n} I_n\subset \prod_{n\ge 2}T_n(F) $ is such a non-nilpotent nildeal."?

Comment: @Jak: I've added details. Is that clearer?

Comment: Is $I_{n}$ nil-deal?

Comment: @TrevorGunn: Addition and multiplication are component-wise in this algebra.

Comment: @Jak: My typo was a null deal, I'd say ;o)

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not achieve the nilpotency of the ideals "$I_{n}$ and $I$"...help me

Comment: @Jak: Well you should prove that the square of a matrix $A$ in $I_n$ is a matrix with the terms in the first overdiagonal  equal to $0$.  This lets you  write  $A$ as a block matrix  $\begin{pmatrix}0&B\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $B\in I_{n-1}$, and makes it possible to proceed by induction.